# Combining items within an array in VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm very new to VB.net and I have an array, like so,

```
points = [[1,2],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]
```

The result I want is to be able to break this up into pairs, starting with the first item and then combining it with the next item, until the last item is paired with the previous item, like so:

```
new points = [[[1,2],[5,6]],[[5,6],[7,8]],[[7,8],[9,10]]]
```

Doing it without a loop is preferred. Being a python guy, i would do this using a list comprehension with array slicing, I'm interested to see how it would look like in VB.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Is that a rectangular or jagged array?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be:

```
Dim pointPairs = Enumerable.Range(0, points.Length - 2).Select(Function(n) Tuple.Create(points(n), points(n + 1)))
```

That will give you an `IEnumerable(Of Tuple(Of Point, Point))`.  You could then enumerate that directly or call `ToArray` or `ToList`, e.g.

```
Dim pointPairs = Enumerable.Range(0, points.Length - 2).
                            Select(Function(n) Tuple.Create(points(n), points(n + 1))).
                            ToArray()
```

Comment: I tried doing ToArray() at the end, it's throwing a compiler error saying that tuple cannot be converted to array?

Comment: Then you called `ToArray` in the wrong place.  You call it on the `IEnumerable`, not the `Tuple`.

Comment: You're turning something very easy into something difficult.  You simply stick a `ToArray` call on the end of the expression.  See my edit above.  Also, note that I corrected the second argument to `Enumerable.Range`.

Comment: You need to go from 0 to points.Length / 2, and then take n * 2 and n * 2 + 1 for each Tuple

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, That's what I thought at first too but take another look at the example provided in the question.  It's not first paired with second and third paired with fourth.  It's first paired with second, second paired with the third and third paired with fourth, etc.  Every element is paired with the following element so all but the first and last elements get paired twice.

Comment: @jm See my comment. I already tried that, already, as confirmed in your update. It throws  "Implicit conversion of system.tuple frome 1-dimensional array of System.Tuple to ICollection(MapPoint) is disallowed."

Comment: It's rather hard for us to provide accurate and complete advice when you don;t give us accurate and complete information to begin with. We're not mind-readers. Your first comment said that the error was that a `Tuple` could not be converted to an array, which meant that you were calling `ToArray` in the wrong place. Your latest comment mentions a quite different error message and thus indicates a quite different mistake on your part. That mistake is assuming that my example could be plugged into your code without change even though you never told us what you actually need.

Comment: If you need `MapPoint` objects then you probably ought to create `MapPoint` objects. Creating `Tuple` objects won't help you much. Look at my code example, see where it creates a `Tuple` and change it to create a `MapPoint` instead. In that case, calling `ToArray` or `ToList` will successfully create an `ICollection(Of MapPoint)` because both an array and a generic `List` implement `ICollection(Of T)`.